# VFSVolumeSize overflow on 6GB+ cards on Palm Centro

Tags: palm-os

When I call VFSVolumeSize on Palm OS on a Palm Centro with a 6GB SanDisk card inserted, it returns 1810366464 as the size of the card but 2098102272 bytes used.  Obviously there's an overflow going on with the card size.

Is there a way to detect this overflow and get the real size of the card?

Answer (score 1):

There's no great way to do this.  The VFSVolumeSize API only uses 32-bit values, so it can't correctly report a size greater than 4GB.  There are expansion manager APIs that can tell you about the card slot, but none of them talk about block size or number of blocks for the card.

You'll see the same failure if you go into the Card Info app on the device — it will also improperly indicate the card's size.